# Detect if HTML5 video is local

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask how to detect if the video source is local or external

Is the best way to use regex to detect video source and define it local or external, like this? => `https?:\/\/`

Or are there an API for this? What is the best practice? Thank you

Thank you.

Comment: `new URL(theVideoSource).protocol` would be `"file:"`. But why would this matter?

Comment: What do you call "local" and "external"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the URL as the `href` of an anchor and check its host.

```js
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '/local';
console.log(a.host === location.host); // internal
a.href = 'https://example.com';
console.log(a.host, location.host);
```